# How do I change a Google account for Android mobile (Xperia 10)?

Tags: google-account, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

When I first set up my Xperia 10 (running Android 1.6) I selected a 'dummy account', not knowing that it might be somewhat difficult to change it afterwards to a real account (I wasn't warned).

I want to avoid hard resets or losing too much data. Is there a recommended procedure for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty easy.

1. Just go to `Settings > Accounts & Sync`
2. Remove the 'dummy' account
3. Add the real account

You can even leave the dummy there for now. Android supports multiple accounts.

*Note: I'm running Android 2.1 so the menu options may be slightly different, but the idea and results should be the same.*

Comment: Note that Android 2.0+ is substantially different when it comes to handling (multiple) sync accounts. There is no Accounts & Sync on 1.6, and the only near equivalent "Data Synchronisation" menu has no option to change accounts.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow Android 1.6 user (I'm on an HTC Magic), I can confirm that there is no easy and safe way to change the Google Account that your phone links to.

Anything you've saved into Google Contacts, Google Calendar, etc can be exported and imported into your other account fairly easy, other settings and data aren't so easy.

Factory resetting your phone is the only real option here, note that if you've bought any apps from the Market you are out of luck here. The Factory Data Reset option is under the SD Card & Phone Storage menu, and you really need to be careful about using it for the reasons above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Settings > Applications > Manage applications`

Scroll down till you find “Google Apps” click on it...

Simply hit the "Clear data"....

Answer (score 0):

Factory Reset is the only option that you have. But be sure that all your data is backed up.

If you are running on Android 2.1 version then you can try [Erazzer Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=dsoft.ErazzerFree) this app to change the primary google account. But to use this app your phone must be rooted.

As you are running on Android 1.6 resetting the phone is the only option you have.

Before doing anything just do a backup of all your data on your phone.