# Only one account showing on Google+ Android app

Tags: google-account, accounts, google-plus

I have two GMail accounts active on my Android 2.2. Let's call them **Acc1** and **Acc2**.

**Acc1 is the default account** I set when I got my Android. I didn't know then, that I can't change the default address. My Acc2 is the main Google account I use everywhere.

When I launch the Google+ app, it only shows the default account but my 2nd account has Google+ activated. All other apps show me both my Acc1 & Acc2 accounts to select. I don't understand why Google+ app doesn't see my other account.

Is there a way set Google+ app to see my Acc2 account or a way to change the default android account without losing all my local data?

I hope I've been clear, thank you!

Comment: According to information on [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/614/change-google-account-for-android-mobile-xperia-10) I think you're looking at a factory reset.

Comment: I think on some phones it's possible to go in and remove both accounts, then add them again in the reverse order, without doing a factory reset.  But that would probably do a "partial wipe", I expect it would erase all your data and just leave your apps.  Not sure, though.

Comment: The app was just updated. There's nothing about what changed in the Market description, but has it made any difference for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.0.2 is out, and appears that it's going to fix your issue.

From the release notes:

> What's in this version:
>
> - Spiffy new profile icon on the menu screen
> - **Handle multiple Gmail accounts on first sign in**
> - Minor UI polish

(emphasis mine)

Unfortunately, I don't have my own invitation to Google+, so I'm not able to test this.

Comment: Great, it works now! I'll send you an invite, just drop me a DM via @edibudimilic on Twitter.

Comment: Let's hope they re-open invitation soon.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to select a different account just by clearing the data for Google+ in Manage Applications. (HTC Desire Z running CyanogenMod 7.1 RC1)

I would really prefer to be able to switch accounts on the fly, though, much like the GMail app currently allows.

Also I'm reconsidering my Google lifestyle -- might try to consolidate my many accounts...

Comment: Version 1.0 didn't have support for multiple accounts. That was quickly rectified in v1.0.2. And now I have my Google+ invitation, so I'm off to the races.

Answer (score -1):

It's not seeing the default account, just the first one listed, alphabetically.  It's a limitation of the app.  You can work around this bug by temporarily removing **Acc1** account.

1. Go to `Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync` screen.
2. Tap on your **Acc1** account, and tap the "Remove account" button.
3. Launch the Google+ app and it should see your **Acc2** account and allow you to sign in with it.
4. Go back to `Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync` screen.
5. Re-add your **Acc1** account.

**Edit**
Google just update the Google+ app to handle multiple GMail accounts.

Comment: I've tried that. It gives me an error: *This account is required by some applications. You can only remove it by resetting the phone to factory defaults..*

Comment: I've seen this error on MotoBLUR phones.  Which handset do you have?

Comment: I have Samsung Galaxy Ace with 2.2-Froyo. Can't remove the main account so I need to wait for a Google+ App fix from Google. Just found out on their groups they are aware of the problem and working on it now.