# Change main Google account login address

Tags: gmail, google-account

When I activated my first Android phone, the Galaxy Note, last week it forced me to create a Gmail account for it.

Seeing no other way out, I did as I was told.

However, seeing yet another google mail address pop up was quite annoying, so I decided to try to get rid of it.

I managed to remove Gmail from my account permanently, and go back to my normal e-mail address to login to Google, but my Android device isn't following. It still has the gmail address set as login.

Is there a way to just change the login address? The account behind it is the same.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2569/981, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/614/981

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't rooted, you've to do factory data reset to change your primary Gmail acccount. (Settings > Privacy > Factory data reset.)

If you are rooted then you can use a file manager program to rename  /data/system/accounts.db file and restart the phone.

You can find the detail steps with illustration [here](http://www.technipages.com/android-change-main-google-account.html).